# Store value depending the clicked button

Tags: laravel

I got a question here...

I’m trying to update a value on the database through buttons. But I really don’t know how to set a specific value of a button. I just want to perform this action through only one link.

example: `/status/update/{id}`

But, thing is that the status will depend on the button clicked.

So for example.

A user submits a song to get promoted, the promoter will have 3 options:

Accept demo, decline demo & shortlist demo.

When the promoter clicks on shortlist for example, the song should appear as “shortlisted, accepted or declined”, thing is that i don’t know even how in the controller i can perform this, I’ve got only the idea of creating separate functions and routes for each button… but i want to simplify it.

Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

Comment: For strictness ... please consider obeying the http verbs and using post/put.  Perhaps a form where the change action auto-submits.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the status you want to set like so: `/status/update/{id}/{status}` and then in your controller you can get the value from `$request->status`.

Each button will have its own url, something like:

`<a href="{{ route('route here', 'accept') }} class="btn">Accept</a>`

`<a href="{{ route('route here', 'decline') }} class="btn">Decline</a>`